# Unable to send a message to a remote Kafka

Tags: python-2.7, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to connect to a remote Kafka server, but I'm not able to pass a SimpleClient error. The Kafka server is already running and there is already a Kafka topic created for my device. Do I need to setup something else before trying to write to Kafka?

```
from kafka import SimpleProducer, SimpleClient
kafka = SimpleClient(hosts=["XX.XX.XXX.XXX:2181"]) # remote Ip:port
producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
topic = "testTopic"

producer.send_messages(topic,"Test message")
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/..../kafkaProducer.py", line 6, in <module>
    client = SimpleClient(hosts=["xxx:2181"])

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kafka\client.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.load_metadata_for_topics()  # bootstrap with all metadata

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kafka\client.py", line 531, in load_metadata_for_topics
    resp = self.send_metadata_request(topics)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kafka\client.py", line 596, in send_metadata_request
    return self._send_broker_unaware_request(payloads, encoder, decoder)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kafka\client.py", line 186, in _send_broker_unaware_request
    raise KafkaUnavailableError('All servers failed to process request: %s' % hosts)
kafka.errors.KafkaUnavailableError: KafkaUnavailableError: All servers failed to process request: [('XX.XX.XX.162', 2181, 0)]
```

Update: Kafka was not running on the server and the port is 9092.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=["XX.XX.XXX.XXX:9092"]) # remote Ip:port
topic = "testTopic"
producer.send(topic,"Test message")
```

Comment: It looks like `kafka` is not running on that system.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this Python client but are you sure you want to connect to 2181 as that is the zookeeper port. Are you sure you don't want 9092 which is the Kafka port?

Comment: Hans & AChampion: You are both correct. Kafka was not running when I was running this script and the port should be 9092.